# Weight prediction using NNs

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I’m relatively new to the topic of machine learning, so naturally I have a couple of issues that I hope you can help me with or lead me in the right direction. I had a project before, during which we collected data of people walking normally and also with a stone in their shoe. We measured Acceleration and also with a gyroscope sensor. Based on this data I build a neural network that can classify the signals into normal or impaired walking. So two possible outputs. 
Now my idea is this: I want to, using the same data, build a network that can predict the weights of the participants (it was also recorded). 
Based on this my three questions:
-   What kind of network structure is most suitable for such a task? (Dense, CNN, LSTM,…)
-   Before the network basically had two options to answer from (normal or impaired walking) but now I have a continuous range of answers… How can this be approached?
-   How can I make sure the network initializes with a sensible prediction?
I hope all the questions make sense. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and most likely off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NNa architecture you prefer:

If you work with sequences use 1d convolutionals or RNNs.

As you are dealing with a regression problem you have to have a single neuron as output without activation function.

Take a.look [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb) to learn to solve a regression problem with RNNs

Comment: Thank you very much I will have a look at it!